# ParallelStream with Maps

Tags: parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I want to read values from complex map and execute one function in parallel way. For that I am using ForkJoinPool from Java 8.

Issue I am facing here is, for few values, function is executed twice.
Initially I thought, Hashmap is not thread safe so I have tried to use HashTable, but its the same...

```
final Map<CakeOrder, List<CakeOrderDetails>> cakeOrderMap = cakeUpdatesQueueItemDao.getCakeOrdersByStatus(EItemStatus.OPENED, country.getDbTableSuffix(), true);
final Map<CakeOrder, List<CakeOrderDetails>> cakeOrderTableMap = new Hashtable<>();

cakeOrderMap.forEach((k, v) -> cakeOrderTableMap.put(k, v));

final ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(20);
pool.submit(() -> cakeOrderTableMap.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .parallel()
   .forEach(entry -> cakeService.updateCakeOrderStatusAndPrice(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))).invoke();
```

Comment: Note that the last sentence of Hashtable documentation says that it is recommended to use ConcurrentHashMap instead of Hashtable. Also you can intantiate a Hashtable from a HashMap directly, just pass it to constructor.

Comment: Btw there's `cakeOrderTableMap.putAll(cakeOrderMap)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parallel stream the thread-safety of the input collection is unnecessary as long as it's not updated. On the other way, `Hashtable.entrySet()` is a very bad source for parallel stream as `Hashtable` does not have custom spliterator implementation. Using `HashMap` is much better. Nevertheless, the provided code everything should work correctly, either with `HashMap` or with `Hashtable` (though much less efficient with `Hashtable`). I suspect that the problem is inside not shown here `cakeService.updateCakeOrderStatusAndPrice` which is likely to be not thread-safe.